# Show validation error message on input type file Form Control, if File Format is not doc or docx

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want an alert to show up if the user submits a file and it isn't of type `doc` or `docx`. I've written a validator for this and would like the alert to show (Unacceptable file type) if the validator isn't passed.

Typescript:

```
this.resume_form = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required, this.nameValidator]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern(emailRegExp)]],
  resume: ['', [Validators.required, this.fileValidator]],
  cv: []
})

fileValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {
    [key: string]: boolean
  } | null => {
    let filename = control.value;
    filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.validFileTypes.length; i++) {
      console.log(filename + " " + " " + this.validFileTypes[i]);
      if (filename === this.validFileTypes[i]) {
        return null;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="resume"> Resume*</label>
  <input type="file" id="resume" class="form-control-file" formControlName="resume" required>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="resume_form.controls.resume.errors?.required && resume_form.controls.resume.touched required">Please Upload File </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" *ngIf="resume_form.controls.resume.errors?.resume">Unacceptable File Type </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll have to handle the `change` event on the `<input type="file" />`

Here, once you get the file list, you'll have to check for the valid file name and then `setErrors` on the `FormControl` accordingly.

So you can use the [**`setErrors(...)`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setErrors) API on an [**`AbstractFormControl`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) for this.

Give this a try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  resume_form: FormGroup;
  validFileTypes = ['doc', 'docx'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resume_form = this.fb.group({
      resume: ['', [Validators.required]],
    })
  }

  onChange($event) {
    const fileName = $event.target.files[0].name;
    const fileEntension = fileName.split('.').pop();
    if (this.validFileTypes.indexOf(fileEntension) > -1) {
      this.resume_form.controls['resume'].setErrors(null);
    } else {
      this.resume_form.controls['resume'].setErrors({ resume: true });
    }
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div 
  class="form-group"
  [formGroup]="resume_form">
    <label for="resume">Resume*</label>
  <input 
    type="file" 
    id="resume" 
    class="form-control-file" 
    formControlName="resume"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    required>
  <div 
    class="alert alert-warning" 
    *ngIf="resume_form.controls.resume.errors?.required && resume_form.controls.resume.touched required">
    Please Upload File
  </div>
  <div 
    class="alert alert-warning" 
    *ngIf="resume_form.controls.resume.errors?.resume">
    Unacceptable File Type
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-file-format-validators?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.